# Slowing down the playback speed of an audio file

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, audio, core-audio, ios4

I'm trying to do is slow down the audio in an audio file I'm playing programmatically using the iPod player in an app.

I've read that this is possible now in iOS 4 (supposedly they gave us access to the raw sound data from songs in the iPod library, which makes no sense to me given the DRM situation), and I've looked through the new APIs, but saw nothing relevant, I'm sure due to my own inexperience.

Thanks a ton for any tips.

Comment: Where did you see that you can access the raw sound data? I see APIs for using the iPod music player and accessing the library, but nothing about actually dealing with the song as data or anything else, and no speed controls.

Comment: Here:
http://www.cybergsm.com/ios-4-adds-direct-access-to-itunes-library-iphone-dj-apps-about-to-get-crazy